# Unable to create thumbnail while image is uploading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create thumbnail of image while it is uploading. The problem is that the thumbnail isn't created at all. Also is not saved in database.

This is what I have added in my function

```
    $image = $request->file('image');

    if( $image && $image->isValid()){

        $imagename = str_random(20).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
        $thumb_img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(100, 100);
        $thumb_img->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $image->move($destinationPath, $imagename);                    
    }

    $item->image = $filename;
    $item->image_thumb = $thumb_img;
```

It's saves only the original image both places - `uploads` dir and in database but nothing regarding the thumbnail.

I'm using Intervention package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is saving because you override the same image twice. Look what you have:

First, you creating `thumbnail` and saves it into the `/uploads`

After this, you save the original into the same directory with same name e.g. overriding the thumb.

You just need to make different name for the thumbnail:

```
$thumb_img = Image::make($image)->resize(100, 100)->save($destinationPath.'/thumb_'.$imagename, 80);
```

Notice the prefix for the thumb `thumb_`...